The file is not visible even though I changed the branch using Gitflow
I cloned it again and set up Gitflow to change the branch from main to development, but the file is not visible.
After deleting the file, I cloned it again and set up Gitflow again, but it was the same. Can we try again? Or is there another way?

It sounds like there might be an issue with the cloned repository or Gitflow setup. Try these step,

Check branch: Ensure you're on the correct branch (development) using git branch.
Fetch updates: Run git fetch --all to make sure all branches and files are up to date.
Switch branch: Run git checkout development to ensure you're on the right branch.
Check for untracked files: Run git status to see if the file is untracked or ignored.
Clone again: If needed, delete the local folder, clone the repo again, and repeat the process.

If the issue persists there may be a problem with the repository itself.
